# How to make a bottom sheet with height follow the amount of item of JSON

Tags: flutter, dart, bottom-sheet

`BottomSheet` in Flutter so that the height follows the number of items (data from JSON) is that what? Because I made the height not follow the amount of data but followed 1/2 the screen of each cellphone. So if the phone is long, there is empty space at the bottom. If the cellphone is short, the data is cut by the screen below.

This is the code for creating bottom sheet:

```
void _showModalBottomSheet(AsyncSnapshot<CatlistResult> snapshot) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext bc) {
          return Card(
            elevation: 3.0,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(15), topRight: Radius.circular(15))),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, top: 10.0, right: 16.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/main/more_2lines_20dp.png', scale: 3.5),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: GridView.builder(
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //kill scrollable
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshot == null ? 0 : snapshot.data.catlist.length,
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 4),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        var numItems = snapshot.data.catlist[index];
                        if (numItems.f == 1) {
                          if (numItems.b == 0) {
                            return GestureDetector(
                              child: Card(
                                elevation: 0.0,
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Image.asset('assets/images/main/cat_${numItems.a}.png', fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 50.0, height: 50.0),
                                    Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        numItems.c,
                                        maxLines: 2,
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }
```

And this is the result of my code:

1. Run from iOS Emulator

[image: Run from iOS Emulator]

2. Run from Android Emulator

[image: Run from Android Emulator]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problems:**

1. In your parent `Column` you are using

   ```
   mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max
   ```
2. You are also using `Expanded` in this `Column` which creates the empty space if there are less items in the `GridView`. Remove this `Expanded` widget.

---

**Solution:**

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // 1st use min not max
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(...),
    GridView.builder(...), // 2nd remove Expanded
  ],
)
```

Comment: To complete the answer, if you get the issue that `hasSize` is not true anymore when you remove the `Expanded` widget, you can instead replace `Expanded` by `Flexible`